# Search in Eclipse through project

Tags: eclipse

How to search in Eclipse through project for some word ? When I start CTRL-h I need to choose field, method or ...., but I need to find all occurences in project no metter method, field or .. ! How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> -> File Search -> Containing Text 'some word'
make sure the scope is set to workspace or enclosing projects. Choosing Selected Resources will narrow the result set to the folder or file you selected in the explorer.

Further if you know the file type that might contain the text you can use the `File Name patterns` with values like `*.php, *.phtml, *.html`

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> might help finding Text in the new Version of Eclipse 3.7.

Answer (score 4):

In order to accomplish it you need to customize your research:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

then at the bottom of the search window click on <kbd>Customize</kbd>

check only `FileSearch` and unselect the rest of the options

then you can search for anywork in the project by selecting either `worksapce` or `Enclosing project`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [InstaSearch Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch) you can easily filter searches by project:

`proj:MyProjectName textToFind`

or use ui to select a project to search in.