# Search in particular Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, search, project

Is there any way to specify a project, where you want to search?
It's been annoying me for a long time. Like when I hit Ctrl+H to search, the only scopes available are:

1. Workspace
2. Selected resources
3. Enclosing projects
4. Working set

So, the only 3 ways I see to perform a search in particular projects are:

- Open a file from the required project, hit Ctrl+H and choose **Enclosing projects** scope
- Add required project to **Working set**, and perform search on this set.
- Select a project in **Project Explorer** and search in **Selected resources**

All of these methods are not always convenient.
Sometimes, I just want to manually specify projects, where the search is to be performed

**Edit:**
The last option is not good for 2 reasons:

1) I usually have "Link with editor" option on, which associates currently opened file with corresponding item in Project Explorer. Our project is quite large, so usually I would have to scroll all the way up to collapse the selected project to make others visible.

2) Also, Project Explorer is not reachable when I'm working in another perspective, such as Debug for example (I know I can add it through *Window->Show View*, but that just breaks the essence of perspectives).

Comment: In what way do you find your 3rd option inconvenient? It does exactly what you need; you manually specify projects and search on them only.

Comment: @Giorgos Dimtsas, see the Edit

Comment: There are answers in a similar question:
[search-in-eclipse-through-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469014/search-in-eclipse-through-project/9801957#9801957)

Comment: @Andrejs thanks, for that `InstaSearch` plugin suggestion. This seems like something I might want to try. If you post your answer here, I would gladly accept it.